# Change the color of the characters in whitespace-mode

Tags: emacs, colors, whitespace

I have recently moved from Geany to Emacs and I would like to customize the whitespace characters in Emacs to look like the ones in Geany.

With Geany, the dots are tiny and grey:

[image: Sample code with Geany]

With Emacs, the dots are larger and white:

[image: Sample code with Emacs]

I find the dots in Geany much lighter on the eyes.

**SOLUTION**

The problem was solved after I commented `(setq whitespace-style (quote (spaces tabs newline space-mark tab-mark newline-mark)))` from my .emacs file:

```lisp
;; make whitespace-mode use just basic coloring
;;(setq whitespace-style (quote (spaces tabs newline space-mark tab-mark newline-mark)))
(setq whitespace-display-mappings
  ;; all numbers are Unicode codepoint in decimal. ⁖ (insert-char 182 1)
  '(
    (space-mark 32 [183] [46]) ; 32 SPACE 「 」, 183 MIDDLE DOT 「·」, 46 FULL STOP 「.」
    (newline-mark 10 [182 10]) ; 10 LINE FEED
    (tab-mark 9 [9655 9] [92 9]) ; 9 TAB, 9655 WHITE RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE 「▷」
    ))
```

The whitespace characters now look exactly as expected.

Comment: Instead of commenting the line you could have added `face` to the `whitespace-style` list.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> `whitespace-space` <kbd>RET</kbd>

(maybe start with a foreground colour of around `gray30`, and adjust from there.)

in elisp, something like:

```el
(set-face-attribute 'whitespace-space nil :background nil :foreground "gray30")
```

(There might be a smaller dot than the one you're using, but I don't know what that would be offhand.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, M-x customize-face RET whitespace-space RET and colour set to light grey doesn't change anything. The dots still appear pure white.

Comment: @Mathieu: just to be sure, did you click the "Apply" button after changing the colour?

Comment: @phils, I have edited my question to take your point into consideration. It looks like the whitespace-space face is not related to the colour of the dots.

Comment: I suspect the colour theme you're using conflicts somehow, as that should work in a default config (test with `emacs -Q`). However, if you place the cursor on a space (in your current config) and type `C-u C-x =` you should be able to see which faces are being used (and customize them, if it seems sensible).

Comment: You are right, if I revert back to emacs' default theme instead of using zenburn, I can customize the colour of whitespace characters the way you suggest. In other words, in the general case, your solution does the trick. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here is an alternative that does not slow down Emacs in large buffers:  `(let* ( (my-glyph-pilcrow (make-glyph-code ?\u00B6 'lawlist-purple-face)) (my-glyph-space (make-glyph-code ?\u00B7 'whitespace-space-face)) (my-glyph-tab (make-glyph-code ?\u203A 'tab-face)) ) (aset (or buffer-display-table (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))) ?\n '[,my-glyph-pilcrow ?\n]) (aset (or buffer-display-table (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))) ?\ '[,my-glyph-space]) (aset (or buffer-display-table (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))) ?\t '[,my-glyph-tab]))`

Comment: The `'` before each square bracket needs to be replaced with a backtick ` [which cannot be done in a comment format setting]; and, the face should be replaced with the user's preferred face. The code could be refined a bit, but that should give everyone the general idea.  Since the thread is locked, I can't post an answer.  This thread was the first to come up with a Google search for *"how to change whitespace color emacs"*, so I thought it was the best one to post this code.

Comment: lawlist: you can `\`[,escape]` backticks in comments. Prefix with a backslash.

Comment: Also, am I correct in understanding that you're presenting a solution which *doesn't* use whitespace mode? If so, it's not directly relevant to this question? If there's not a more-appropriate Q&A, you could ask & answer one yourself (e.g. "How can I display whitespace without using whitespace-mode?"), and simply leave a comment here linking to that.